# hibernate, new line added but values not inserted

Tags: hibernate, struts2

i am using struts2 hibernate and I have a problem when i add a new contact there is a new line in the table contacts but all the values are  all null.

this is the action class

```
public class ContactAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Contact> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Contact contact = new Contact();
private List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
private ContactDAO contactDAO = new ContactDAOImpl();

public Contact getModel() {
    return contact;
}

public String add()
{
    contactDAO.saveContact(contact);
    return SUCCESS;
}

public String list()
{
    contactList = contactDAO.listContact();
    return SUCCESS;
}

public Contact getContact() {
    return contact;
}

public void setContact(Contact contact) {
    this.contact = contact;
}

public List<Contact> getUserList() {
    return contactList;
}

public void setUserList(List<Contact> contactList) {
    this.contactList = contactList;
}
```

this is DAO class

```
public class ContactDAOImpl implements ContactDAO{

@SessionTarget
Session session;
@TransactionTarget
Transaction transaction;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Contact> listContact() {    
    List<Contact> courses = null;
    try {
        courses = session.createQuery("from Contact").list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return courses;
}

public void saveContact(Contact contact) {
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(contact);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

and this the hibernate configuration file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/example1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
        <mapping class="com.example.model.User" />
        <mapping class="com.example.model.Contact" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I used the exact same code for User and there is no issues.

this is the Contact.java class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CONTACTS")
public class Contact {

    private Long contact_id;
    private String contact_firstname;
    private String contact_laststname;
    private String contact_title;
    private String contact_email;
    private String contact_company; 
    private int contact_phone;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="CONTACT_ID")
    public Long getId() {
        return contact_id;
    }
    public void setId(Long contact_id) {
        this.contact_id = contact_id;
    }

    @Column(name="CONTACT_FIRSTNAME")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return contact_firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String contact_firstname) {
        this.contact_firstname = contact_firstname;
    }

    @Column(name="CONTACT_LASTNAME")
    public String getLastName() {
        return contact_laststname;
    }
    public void setlastName(String contact_laststname) {
        this.contact_laststname = contact_laststname;
    }

    @Column(name="CONTACT_TITLE")
    public String getTitle() {
        return contact_title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String contact_title) {
        this.contact_title = contact_title;
    }

    @Column(name="CONTACT_COMPANY")
    public String getCompany() {
        return contact_company;
    }
    public void setCompany(String contact_company) {
        this.contact_company = contact_company;
    }

    @Column(name="CONTACT_PHONE")
    public int getPhone() {
        return contact_phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(int contact_phone) {
        this.contact_phone = contact_phone;
    }

    @Column(name="CONTACT_EMAIL")
    public String getEmail() {
        return contact_email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String contact_email) {
        this.contact_email = contact_email;
    }
}
```

this is the jsp page

```
[<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Add contact</title>
<s:head />
<style type="text/css">
@import url(style.css);
</style>
</head>
<body>
<s:form action="addContact">
    <s:textfield name="contact_firstname" label="First name" />
    <s:textfield name="contact_laststname" label="Last name" />
    <s:textfield name="contact_title" label="Title" />
    <s:textfield name="contact_email" label="Email address" />
    <s:textfield name="contact_company" label="Related company" />
    <s:textfield name="contact_phone" label="Phone number" />
    <s:submit />
</s:form>
</body>
</html>][1]
```

[this is how it shows in the databas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jinfZ.png)

Comment: Where is the Contact.java code? Why don't you try using hibernate annotations?

Comment: I added the Contact.java code

Comment: Don't use modeldriven or do it right.

Comment: Thanks but didn't help

Comment: How did you show the line with values that are null?

Comment: @N.H What exactly have you done to get rid of modeldriven? Show you code.

Comment: Now it s adding the line with values to the database,  I just changed charset from "ISO-8859-1" to "UTF-8" in thhe jsp page, but can't see the result of list() in th jsp page